How number of partition are 12 if I have only 2 cores available?
I am diving deep into pyspark, and understandig internals of PySpark.
While learning above memory management, I came to know that, spark breaks down the files into size of 128MB and each block is stored on a single core.
I created a databrick cluster with only driver node, 0 worker node.
The driver have 15GB memory and 2 cores.
I downloaded a csv file of almost 1.45 GB and read it into a df.
Now the question is,

How it will break the file into 128 MB block , if I have only 2 cores.
when I run the code, df.rdd.getNumPartitions(), it gives me 12. How the partition can be 12, if I    have only 2 cores, assuming that , each [artition is stored on a single core. 12 partitions are possible only when, I have 12 cores.
How spark will read and process files, if number of cores are less than the number of blocks.
Running spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism gives parallelism of 8, but how? I have only 2 cores available on a driver node, 0 workers.

I have tried above things.
